# Creating a symbolic link in a bash script in a different folder

Tags: bash

My bash script is getting two arguments with folders (that exist and everything).

Inside the first one I want to create a link to the second

Suppose I have the folders /home/matt/a and /home/matt/b, I call the script like this :

```
/home/matt # ./my_script ./a ./b
```

I want to see a symbolic link inside a that points to b

And of course, just doing

```
ln -s $2 $1/link
```

in the script does not work... (it will create a link that looks for a ./b inside a)

This is just a very simple example, I am looking for a script that will be generic enough to take different arguments (absolute or relative path...etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
ln -s "$(readlink -e "$2")" "$1/link"
```

if you have `readlink`.

Or perhaps this variation on the answer by larsmans:

```
cd "$2"
dir=$(pwd)
cd -
ln -s "$dir" "$1/link"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $2
ln -s "`pwd`" $1/link
```

Comment: it fails, looking for $1/link inside $2... right now, I am mostly trying by using only relative paths for both arguments...

Comment: Do you have pathnames with spaces in them? That might explain why it doesn't work without proper quoting (as exemplified by Dennis Williamson).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another cute one-liner:

```
ln -s `cd \`dirname $2\`; pwd`/`basename $2` $1/link
```

Comment: You can avoid the awkward escaping by using `$()` instead of backticks: `ln -s "$(cd "$(dirname "$2")"; pwd)/$(basename "$2")" "$1/link"`